# New style casting with QT

Tags: qt

I want to update my code from old style casting to new style one. I have some problems with understanding the different type of casts.

1 case

```
if (((QDataItem*)(*it))->GetType()==QDataItem::AudioTrack){
```

Here I have a class "QDataItem". This contain an enum of track types, like AudioTrack. Basing on a QTreeWidget I iterate through the QTreeWidget items. Each Item represents a QDataItem.  Now with new casting I want to do:

```
if ((static_cast<QDataItem*>(*it))->GetType()==QDataItem::AudioTrack){
```

Is this there right way to do?

2 case
In old style I have a twice casting

```
QAudioTrackItem *audio_track = (QAudioTrackItem*)(QDataItem*)(*it);
```

QAudioTrackItem is like QDataItem a class. I want to do here:

```
QAudioTrackItem *audio_track = reinterpret_cast<QAudioTrackItem*>(*it)
```

But I am not sure that this is correct in case of the missing QDataItem cast.

Is my result ok or do I have a bug?

Comment: Why do you need to cast here at all? What's the type of `*it` and how are all these types related in the class hierarchy?

Comment: Also, `reinterpret_cast` is almost always wrong, it has only few valid use cases. This probably is not one of those... Depends on what you are casting and why.

Comment: Descendants of QObject can be cost downwards with `qobject_cast`, by the way.

Comment: @hyde I iterate through a QTreeWidget with QDataItems. But to get access to the QDataItem "GetType" I need to tell the code that it is not a QTReeWidget Item, but a QDataItem. So casting is in my eyes needed.

Comment: bBut if reinerpret is wrong, what I have to use in replace of (QAudioTrackItem*)(QDataItem*)(*it);? I thought reinterpret cast is a "force" casting. Do in need to replace with tow static_cast?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this there right way to do?

Yes, `(QDataItem*)(*it)` and `static_cast<QDataItem*>(*it)` should be identical with your code.

But if your classes have such inheritance structure:

```
class QDataItem : QObject {};
class QAudioTrackItem : QDataItem {};
```

you should really consider using [qobject_cast<>()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast-1) instead:

```
if (auto item = qobject_cast<QAudioTrackItem *>(*it)) {
    ....
}
```

> Is my result ok or do I have a bug?

Maybe, it depends on how your inheritance structure look like.

If they inherit just like my example above, it's totally OK to use `reinterpret_cast<>()` to convert any pointers between `QObject`, `QDataItem` and `QAudioTrackItem`.

But if your classes have multiple inheritance:

```
class QDataItem {};
class QAudioTrackItem : QObject, QDataItem {};
```

`reinterpret_cast` could kick your ass badly:

```
auto item = new QAudioTrackItem;

auto p1 = reinterpret_cast<QObject *>(item); // OK
auto p2 = reinterpret_cast<QAudioTrackItem *>(p1); // OK

auto p3 = reinterpret_cast<QDataItem *>(item); // Undefined Behavior
auto p4 = reinterpret_cast<QDataItem *>(p1); // Undefined Behavior
```

Comment: Yes, the QAudioTrackItem is: class QAudioTrackItem : public QDataItem. So object cast is the right choice here?

Comment: @ingo Do you mean QTreeWidgetItem? If QDataItem is a alias or subclass of QTreeWidgetItem, then no. QTreeWidgetItem does not inherit QObject, so you can't use qobject_cast<>() in this case.